# Spring check if request header value contains space

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am sending a request from Postman, with the header `"Api-Version": "                1"`

The response status is `200`, but I am expecting to throw `400`

In a filter class which extends OncePerRequestFilter, I have the following code snippet:

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {

            String reqClientKey = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Api-Version");
        ...
```

The value of `reqClientKey` is `"1"` instead of `"         1"`.

Why the value gets trimmed? How can I get the spaces as well?

Answer (score 1):

The rest specification [RFC 7230](https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#field.parsing) states the following under the ”field parsing” section.

> The field value does not include any leading or trailing whitespace

So leading or trailing whitespaces are not allowed in header values

Comment: Are not allowed, but I am getting 200 OK status, I need to throw a 400 response status

Comment: there is no specification as to how this should be handled. Spring has handled this by trimming. Then you should open a issue on github and state your case. The functionality you are asking for as to my knowledge does not exist.

Comment: it says `OWS (optional white space) occurring before the first non-whitespace octet of the field value or after the last non-whitespace octet of the field value ought to be excluded by parsers when extracting the field value from a header field.` so it should be excluded (removed) by the parsers